# How to apply custom validation on checkout shipping form field?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.0

Magento Version : 2.3.1

I want to apply custom validation on the custom field of the checkout shipping form.

Please suggest to me, how can achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Create custom JS validator**

**app/code/Acme/StackExchange/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```js
let config = {
    "config": {
        "mixins": {
            'Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/validator': {
                'Acme_StackExchange/js/validator-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**app/code/Acme/StackExchange/view/frontend/web/js/validator-mixin.js**

```js
define([
    'jquery',
    'jquery/validate'
], function ($) {
    "use strict";

    return function (validator) {
        validator.addRule('validate-custom-logic', function (v, e) {
            // your logic here

            return true;
        }, $.mage.__("Please enter a valid ..."));

        return validator;
    };
});
```

**2. Set validator to related fields with jsLayout**

**app/code/Acme/StackExchange/etc/frontend/di.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="Acme_StackExchange_Plugin_Checkout_LayoutProcessorPlugin" sortOrder="10"
                type="Acme\StackExchange\Plugin\Checkout\LayoutProcessorPlugin"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**app/code/Acme/StackExchange/Plugin/Checkout/LayoutProcessorPlugin.php**

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Acme\StackExchange\Plugin\Checkout;

use Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor;

class LayoutProcessorPlugin
{
    /**
     * @param LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $result
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterProcess(
        LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array $result
    ): array {
        // extend shipping address form
        $this->extendAddressFields($result['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']);

        return $result;
    }

    protected function extendAddressFields(array &$jsLayout)
    {
        $jsLayout['YOUR_FIELD']['validation']['validate-custom-logic'] = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Victor Tihonchuk

I used your solution and it's works well

Comment: What we need to put on YOUR_FIELD?

Comment: @LucasD.A.W. <YOUR_FIELD> means form field name in that you need to put validation.